# Python Selenium1

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

Hey im new to python selenium developing, and i kinda need some help if any one have some extra time:)

Im using this site: https://www.youlikehits.com/retweets.php Im trying to click on confirm button the green one. But for some reson i cant figure out how to click it. Every try it says that it cant locate it.

Do you guys have any ide?

Screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z31In.png
Screen of html code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/herDB.png

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Confirm').click()


try:
        print("Trying")
        print("Making points Click")
        time.sleep(5)
except NoSuchAttributeException:
        print("Element not found!")
        continue
except:
        print("Something els is wrong!")

driver.quit()
```

Best Regards Felix

Comment: where the green button is ??

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far and also html in text format.

Comment: The green button is highlighted in the picture, the secound one far down. Stack arent alowing me to add the html code for some reson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Confirm` link is inside an iframe and you need to switch to iframe first inorder to access the element.

Use `WebDriverWait()` wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()` and follwoing css selector
Use `WebDriverWait()` wait for `element_to_be_clickable()` and follwoing xpath

```
driver.get("url")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src^='retweetrender.php']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(.,'Confirm')]"))).click()
```

OR

```
driver.get("url")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src^='retweetrender.php']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Confirm"))).click()
```

You need following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks alot for help!, its now all working.

Comment: Do you have any tips on where to studdy more on python selenium? :)

Comment: You can learn ExplicitWait https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html here